# Async pipes should not be negated

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint, codelyzer

I migrated from TSLint to ESLint following [the guide](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-an-angular-cli-project-from-codelyzer-and-tslint). Now, I get this error message :

> Async pipes should not be negated. Use (observable | async) === (false | null | undefined) to check its value instead

And here is the [given explanation](http://codelyzer.com/rules/template-no-negated-async/) :

> Angular’s async pipes emit null initially, prior to the observable emitting any values, or the promise resolving. This can cause negations, like *ngIf=”!(myConditional | async)” to thrash the layout and cause expensive side-effects like firing off XHR requests for a component which should not be shown.

But I don't understand the proposed solution, particularly the bitwise OR : `false | null | undefined`. When I try to write `(false | null | undefined)` in a template, Angular seems to consider `null` and `undefined` as pipes (which seems legit) and throws an error message. Even outside of an html template, this bitwise OR just returns 0 so, what is the point ? I also tried `false || null || undefined` but it is actually equivalent to `undefined`

Did I miss something ? Or is the error message misleading ? How should I write it then ?

The best I have is this but it is pretty ugly :

```
(observable | async) === false || (observable | async) === undefined
```

Comment: I would guess they mean _"`(observable | async) === false` or `(observable | async) === null` or `(observable | async) === undefined`"_ (i.e. depending on what the value you were checking for actually was), but using the same syntax for two different things makes it ambiguous.

Comment: Seems highly plausible. I will try to submit a PR to propose another text :)

Answer (score 3):

As another way to compare the values from the observable, you can create your own pipes:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'isFalsy',
  pure: false,
})
export class IsFalsyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): any {
    return value ? false : true;
  }
}
```

Import in your module and then compare it like this:

```
<div *ngIf="observable$ | async | isFalsy"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue is:

> Negating an async pipe in an *ngIf thrashes the layout because the
> pipe emits null immediately before checking the condition. This can
> lead cause unnecessary rendering work and trigger component events
> which cause XHR's or other work to be done that shouldn't be needed.

Solution :

```
<div *ngIf="!!(observable$ | async)"></div>
```

Here is the detail you can explore more : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44867

Comment: Your "solution" is wrong, because it will render the if when the value is truthy, but the OP wants to render when the value is falsy.